# Is it bad that 0% of users have fulfulled their commitments?

Tags: discussion

In all other aspects our beta appears fairly healthy.

Upon looking at the list of top users and their contributions on Area 51, it looks like most of them have twice as many answers as questions.

I haven't fulfilled my commitment because as a non-native speaker, I can't even read most of the questions, let alone answer them. However, I'm definitely in the minority of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commitment can only be fulfilled after the site gets to the **Public** Beta.

[Commitment fulfilled before public beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99269/commitment-fulfilled-before-public-beta)